# Can Java Sets test for duplicates elements without order mattering, when the elements are lists of integers?

Tags: java, set

I'm working with a `Set<List<Integer>>` and thought that it would be able to recognize duplicate lists, without order mattering (in the `List<Integer>`), but apparently it considers lists with the same elements and different orders as unique elements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet();
        
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList();
        
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(2);
        set.add(l1);
        
        System.out.println(set);
        
        l2.add(1);
        l2.add(2);
        set.add(l2);
        
        System.out.println(set);
        
        l3.add(2);
        l3.add(1);
        set.add(l3);
        
        System.out.println(set);
        

    }
    


}
```

The output shows no change when adding a list with the same elements & order, but when order is reversed, it is considered unique:

```
[[1,2]]
[[1,2]]
[[1,2], [2,1]]
```

Is there some way to test, regardless of order, for duplicates?
Originally, I was working with a list of list of integers `List<List<Integer>>`, so if there is some way to do so within that, that would be even better.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Set<Set<Integer>>`

Comment: A good thought, but this wouldn't work for what I need. The sublists that I'm adding to the parent list need to be able to contain duplicate values e.g. [-2, 1, 1]. Making the sublists `Set<Integer>`'s would turn [-2, 1, 1] into [-2, 1].

Answer (score 1):

> lists with the same elements and different orders

[That's because](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

> two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

If you want equality based on contents *but not order*, you are looking for something besides list equality. Perhaps you could use a `Set`. Otherwise, you'd need to write either a custom comparator (which would get extremely expensive; you could easily get into O(n^3 log n) territory) or a custom wrapper that kept a pair of lists, the original and a sorted copy for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My post is asking about `Set`. Originally, I was working with `List<List<Integer>>`, but I tried `Set<List<Integer>>` thinking it would take care of the ordering. It does not though (the original post code).

I did make a custom method for testing, and it does work, but like you said it is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use containsAll() method available in the list before adding to the set. If it returns true don't add to the set.

Comment: Okay that is actually exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

But now I'm a little confused on something new. These were actually the first things I tried list.contains() list.containsAll(). But I did so as:

if(list.containsAll(l2) == false)
{
list.add(l2);
}

This made sense to me, as it's saying "if this is not in the list, add it".

However, now I just reversed it to be:

if(list.containsAll(l2) == true)
{
list.add(l2);
}

Which does what I am intending, but makes no sense to me logically. Isn't this saying "if this IS in the list, add it"?

Comment: Sorry a lot of edits/accidental posting ^

Comment: You have to loop over your set. Suppose there 3 object in your set and you are trying to add a new list object to set. Then before adding you should loop through set and check that list is matching with the list you are trying to add. Hope it helps.

Comment: According to how I'm trying it now: `if(list.containsAll(sublist))`, it is correctly checking without having to loop over the parent list